# Deriving the transformation function of a random variable from the original and the final distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Consider a random variable $X$ and consider that this variable can be either real or integral (so I would like to cover both cases: continuos and discrete random variables). Consider to transform this variable using a certain function $g(\cdot)$:

$$Y = g(X)$$

Consider to know both $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$: the probability mass functions of the original r.v. and the final (transformed) r.v.

In better words, I am asking you to consider a random variable and to apply a transformation. Generally we know the transformation, but in our case we know that we want to transform the original r.v. in order to get a final r.v. that we already know!

Is it possible to calculate $g(\cdot)$ from these conditions?

#### PS

Of course I know that there are closed expressions to express the final pdf in terms of $g$ and $f_X(x)$. For a continuos r.v.:

- When $g$ in monotonic increasing: $f_Y(y) = f_X(g^{-1}(y)) \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial y}g^{-1}(y)$.
- When $g$ in monotonic decreasing: $f_Y(y) = -f_X(g^{-1}(y)) \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial y}g^{-1}(y)$.

For a discrete r.v.: $f_Y(y) = f_X(g^{-1}(y))$.

But I cannot get $g$ from these relations being this term inside a function composition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For continuous random variables, the
easiest way to approach your problem is in two steps. First transform $X$ into a random variable $Z \sim U(0,1)$, and then transform $Z$ into $Y$.
The transformations needed are
$$Z = F_X(X), ~~ Y = F_{Y}^{-1}(Z)$$
where $F_X(\cdot)$ is the *cumulative* probability distribution function of
$X$ and $F_Y(\cdot)$ is the  *cumulative* probability distribution function of
$Y$. If the inverse function $F_{Y}^{-1}$ is not uniquely defined, one needs to
pay special attention.

If $X$ and $Y$ are discrete random variables, then
it might be that there are *no* transformations that will map $X$ into $Y$.
For example, $X$ is a Bernoulli random variable while $Y$ is a binomial
random variable with parameters $(n,p)$ where $n > 1$.

Comment: Just a question, how can I make the transformation when X and Y are discrete? $F_Y^{-1}(y)$ cannot be done...